# Printing a list without line breaks (but with spaces) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print the values of a list without line breaks using `sys.stdout.write()`. It works great, but the only problem is that I want to space each value from another. In other words, instead of `123`, I want `1 2 3`. I looked on the website for a solution, but I haven't found something that involves lists.

When I add `" "` to `sys.stdout.write(list[i])`, like this: `sys.stdout.write(list[i], " ")`, it doesn't print at all. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Here's my code:

```
import random
import sys

list = []

length = input("Please enter the number of elements to be sorted: ") 
randomNums = input("Please enter the number of random integers to be created: ") 
showList = raw_input("Would you like to see the unsorted and sorted list? y/n: ")

for i in range(length):
    list.append(random.randint(1,randomNums))

if(showList == "y"):
    for i in range(length):
       sys.stdout.write(list[i], " ")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
sys.stdout.write(" ".join(list))
```

The above will only work if `list` contains strings. To make it work for any list:

```
sys.stdout.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in list))
```

Here we use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to convert each item in the list to a string.

If your list is large and you'd like to avoid allocating the whole string for it, the following approach will also work:

```
for item in list[:-1]:
    sys.stdout.write(str(item))
    sys.stdout.write(" ")
if len(list) > 0:
    sys.stdout.write(list[-1])
```

And as mentioned in the other answer, don't call your variable `list`. You're actually shadowing the built-in type with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the `list` name.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
sys.stdout.write(" ".join(my_list))
```

Also, it's better not to name your variable `list` as Python already has a built-in type called `list`. Hence, that's why I've renamed your variable to `my_list`.

Comment: Built-in `list` is not a function, it's a type. `type(list)` --> `<type 'type'>`. `type(len)` --> `<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

Comment: I tried what you suggested and `sys.stdout.write(" ".join(myList[i]))`, but they both don't work. Where's my mistake?

Comment: @android: thanks, learned an important distinction. I have updated my answer. @wizardo: `myList[i]` is one element but `join()` should be called with the list as argument.

Comment: @wizardo drop the `[i]` part. Then take a look at the docs for `str.join`. Type this in your python session: `help(str.join)`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I'm sorry for being so pedantic today, but you still mention `list()` which is an instance of the type `list` that also happens to be an empty list: `list() == []` --> `True`.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: I'm sorry, I read the docs, but I still can't get it to work. The error I'm getting is `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`

Comment: @android: Thanks. It works now, but why does it have to be so complicated? I thought Python supposed to make your life easier, but this thing really threw me off. I did the same thing in Java with such an ease.

Comment: @wizardo: You're trying to do it the Java way by looping over the items and printing a space after it. That's not really the Python way: in Python you simply join everything together with a space in between and then print everything together.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, I tried the above solution, but I got a weird output:

for example:
 `my_list = [1,2,3]`

`sys.stdout.write(" ".join(str(x) for x in ss))`

the output is:

`1 2 35`
It will add a number at the end (5).

The best solution, in this case, is to use the print function as follows:

`print(" ".join(str(x) for x in ss), file=sys.stdout)`

the output: `1 2 3`