# Printing a list as a string without parentheses or commas in python

Tags: python

I have the list :: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
created by a loop.

I want it to print

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I've used the `.strip('[]')` to get rid of the parentheses but I cannot get rid of the commas.

Comment: What's the need for strippring off `[`, `]`? It's actually a list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing a list without line breaks (but with spaces) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310078/printing-a-list-without-line-breaks-but-with-spaces-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to mutate the list's respresenting string instead of using it's members to build your specific
representation. This is not the way to go.

Use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to create strings and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the strings with your favorite separator:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(' '.join(map(str, lst)))
```

An alternative with a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(' '.join((str(x) for x in lst)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with another loop, and using a comma after the `print`:

```
for e in your_list:
   print e,
```

**Note:** The comma will avoid printing a new-line character.